# Access - LEFT JOIN Query Most Recent Record Only

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to construct a LEFT JOIN query where the "right" side of the query is only the most recent record related to the "left" side's PK.

The left side of the query is from a table called `Oppportunity`.  This table's PK is `OpportunityID`.

The right side of the query is from a table called `tblNotes` containing `NotesID` as its PK and `NotesDate` as one of its data fields.  `tblNotes` also contains `OpportunityID` as a FK.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT Opportunity.OpportunityID, tblNotes.NotesDate, tblNotes.NotesID
FROM Opportunity LEFT JOIN tblNotes ON Opportunity.OpportunityID = tblNotes.opportunityid 
ORDER BY Opportunity.OpportunityID;
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Here is what I need including the empty fields.

[image]

Based on help I got in another post, I know I could use the MAX `NoteID` for each `OpportunityID`.  Here is what I tried.

```
SELECT Opportunity.OpportunityID, tblNotes.NotesDate, tblNotes.NotesID
FROM Opportunity LEFT JOIN tblNotes ON Opportunity.OpportunityID = tblNotes.opportunityid INNER JOIN
                              (SELECT n.NotesID
                                FROM tblNotes AS n
                                WHERE n.notesId = (select top 1 n2.notesId FROM tblNotes as n2
                                  )         
ORDER BY Opportunity.OpportunityID;
```

Any help the community can offer is most appreciated.  I am very good with Excel but Access is very new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the most recent row *first* before `join`ing:

```
SELECT o.OpportunityID, n.NotesDate, n.NotesID
FROM Opportunity as o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT n.*
      FROM tblNotes as n
      WHERE n.NotesDate = (SELECT MAX(n2.NotesDate)
                           FROM tblNotes as n2
                           WHERE n2.OpportunityID = n.OpportunityID
                          )
     ) as n
     ON o.OpportunityID = n.opportunityid 
ORDER BY o.OpportunityID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following logic. The idea is to add a condition in the `left join` that uses a correlated subquery to filter on the latest `NotesDate` per `OpportunityID`

```
SELECT o.OpportunityID, n.NotesDate, n.NotesID
FROM Opportunity AS o
LEFT JOIN tblNotes AS n 
    ON  n.OpportunityID = o.OpportunityID
    AND n.NotesDate = (
        SELECT MAX(n1.NotesDate)
        FROM tblNotes n1
        WHERE n1.OpportunityID = o.OpportunityID
    )
ORDER BY o.OpportunityID;
```